# debugging 64 bit dumps in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit, debugging

Is there any way to use visual studio to debug a dump of a 32 bit app that was produced on a 64 bit computer. I have got WinDbg working but the output is so jumbled i cant work out whats going on.

Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to debugging with WindDbg get yourself a copy of John Robbins:

[Debugging Microsoft .NET 2.0 Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622027)

It is well worth the investment and has a great introductory section on debugging with WinDbg.

Comment: The chapter Power Debugging covers native mode debugging techniques with WinDbg. You might want to consider the older John Robbins (# ISBN-10: 0735615365 # ISBN-13: 978-0735615366) which is the edition I used when I first came to native mode debugging with WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there a different between a native dump (32 on 32) and a 32 on 64 dump, what do you mean by "jumbled output"?

---

Try loading the symbols for system dlls, [set the symbols path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx) in Visual Studio to the Microsoft public symbols path.

Comment: if you try and debug the 64bit dump it just shows the 64 bit threads that process the 32 bit app. http://lodle.net/public/vis_64bit_dump.jpg and the issue with WingDbg is there is so much information spammed out i cant work out whats going on (as there is around 6 different threads that im interested in and visual studio makes it so easy to debug)